# What is the topological degree of the constant map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

What is the topological degree of the constant map? To me it does not make any sense, once $f$ being the constant map has no regular values.
So, how to proceed?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126, my definition is that counts the signals under change of $Df$.

Comment: You are mistaken in thinking that a constant function between manifolds of the same dimension has no regular values. If the function is not surjective, then all points which are not in its image are regular values (for all its preimages satisfy the required condition!). On the other hand, if the function *is* surjective, then both manifolds are of dimension $0$ then again at every point in the pregimage of tthe (unique) point in the codomain the map has maximal rank, namely zero.

Comment: thank you @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, it was very clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you work in the context of differential topology, let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a constant map and $\dim(M)=\dim(N)>0$, then $f$ is not surjective an elment in $y\in N\setminus f(M)$ is a regular value. Since $f^{-1}(y)$ is empty, the degree is zero.

Comment: thanks again! From where did you study this?